# What is the purpose of the "forKey" parameter when adding a CAAnimation to a layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am *very* new to iOS programming, Objective-C, and programming in general, so please excuse me if you find this question frustratingly simple-minded.

The docs on Apple's website are usually great, but I'm having some trouble trying to wrap my head around certain parts of Core Animation. I want to explicitly animate the position of a CALayer. From what I understand, I need to create a CABasicAnimation object, configure it with fromValue, toValue, etc., then add it to a layer using this method:

```
- (void)addAnimation:(CAAnimation *)anim forKey:(NSString *)key
```

My problem is that I have no idea what the significance of the `forKey:` parameter is. From what I've seen in examples online, it's not required? I suppose it has something to do with key-value coding? (I still don't really understand that, either.) Even if it's not required, I'd like to know what it is so that I can take advantage of its usefulness in my app.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CALayer has several methods for getting the animations that have been added to the layer.  If you want to get, replace, or remove a particular animation from [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) you have to give it the key when you call animationForKey: or removeAnimationForKey:.

You don't have to provide a key, you can use `nil` for the key if you don't have any particular need to find a particular animation by key.

Answer (score 12):

It allows you to override animations. For example, implicit animations created by mutating an implicitly animateable property (such as `opacity`) will use the name of the property as a key. This way if you modify it again (to produce a new animation), the new animation will replace the old one instead of trying to have both animations running simultaneously.

Comment: Agree with Kevin.  The ability to specify a forKey property can stop the implicit animation running when you have an explicit animation.  It is explained really well in the WWDC 2010 Session 424 Video (Core Animation in Practice, Part 1 - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).  It explains it much better than I can.

Answer (score 5):

It's just some identifier for your animation. You can call `animationForKey:` and `removeAnimationForKey:` methods later with the specified key.

Also because layer may have only one animation per unique key, you can use this value as identifier for some type of animations and all `...ForKey:` methods will return/remove/replace most current animation for a given animation type/key.